# How to set color of cell output of jupyter notebook (.ipynb) in VS Code editor?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code, background-color, vscode-extensions

Sometimes it is convenient to deal with **jupyter notebooks** from the **VS Code editor** (faster load, less latency and easier debugging).
Nonetheless, there is a problem that *default theme colors are not contrast enough* to distinguish between input and output cells.

I'm having a hard time to figure out which setting I should change, to, let us say, make **the output cell background** just "dark-grey" (I'm using default VS 2019 Dark theme but other options are also not contrast with `.ipynb` files).
Any help will be welcome.

(I've also come across other similar questions but did not find the turn key solution.)

Example:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem myself, switching different colour themes and when I found the one I like them the colour contrast for the cells is not correct, so I figure out a way you can change that to your linking please see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66400494/how-to-change-cell-background-colour-of-a-jupyter-notebook-cell-in-vscode/66406680#66406680) hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps you, but you can try overriding VSCode's theme by adding this to your settings.json file:

```
{
  "jupyter.ignoreVscodeTheme": true
}
```

If you prefer to use VSCode's gui to edit settings, you can go to your Jupyter extension (assuming you have it installed) => Extension settings => and check "Ignore Vscode Theme".

You need to restart or reload VSCode for this to take effect.

Comment: that seems to work. But do you know where can I change the color of input or output separately?

Comment: Glad to hear! Please mark it as accepted answer if that works for you :)

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible at the moment, after reading some of the issues on github... :(

Comment: This setting slightly improves the contrast between input cell and output. However, there is a warning that "*this setting is deprecated and will be removed in the next release.*" I am currently using VSC 1.61.2.

Answer (score 3):

In the settings.json -- can be found at File(Windows)/Code(Mac)>Preferences>Settings -- click on any link stated "Edit in settings.json"

Adding this into the json will work -- notebook's setting has to be put under the workbench.colorCustomizations.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
"notebook.outputContainerBackgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
  },
```