# How to change cell background colour of a VSCode Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, themes

I would like to know what is the JSON setting to change the background colour of a VSCode Jupyter Notebook cell.

I found the [VSCode Theme colour reference](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getstarted/theme-color-reference/) but I can't find the specific setting to do so.

I found the perfect colour theme but I would like to tweak the background colour cell just a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those interested the setting is:

`"editorWidget.background": "#ff0000",`

To find it, from the command palette I ran:
`Developer: Generate Color Theme from Current Settings`

This will create a new json document with ALL the elements currently affected by your current theme, from there I search for all the occurrences of the hex colour until I found the matching setting.

**UPDATE**: Please see Mark's answer below

Answer (score 8):

Mark's answer is not comprehensive enough. Not sure if it is the best, please try.

In the settings.json --  can be found at File(Windows)/Code(Mac)>Preferences>Settings

Adding this into the json will work -- notebook's setting has to be put under the workbench.colorCustomizations.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "notebook.cellEditorBackground": "#FFFFFF",
  },
```

The rest of the settings you may follow Mark's guide above.

However, customizing the color background alone at jupyter notebook at vscode is not enough, i need the complete best settings including the font colors. Please share if you found the settings for all under notebook. Or can we change the notebook theme only but leaving the rest of vscode theme untouched?

Comment: If you're interested only on the cell output, the following settings works: `notebook.outputContainerBackgroundColor": "#ffffff"`

Answer (score 6):

vscode v1.59 is adding this `colorCustomization`:

`"notebook.cellEditorBackground"`

Also available:

`"notebook.cellBorderColor"`

---

Previously:

That theme color reference link doesn't seem to be kept up-to-date.  See [vscode Theme Color reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) instead.  There are a lot of notebook-related theme colors:

[Notebook colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#notebook-colors)

including:

```
notebook.focusedCellBackground
notebook.selectedCellBackground
```

and many more.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the reference links, much better than what I found back then